# How does MPI blocking send and receive work?

Tags: mpi

I am reading about MPI blocking send and receive, and there are some things I am not sure of.

While doing some research I found this [example](http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS3402/lectures/mpi-slides.pdf) (page 6-7) of MPI blocking send and receive

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  MASTER 0

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int  numtasks, taskid, len, partner, message;
  char hostname[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

  /* need an even number of tasks  */
  if (numtasks % 2 != 0) {
   if (taskid == MASTER) 
    printf("Quitting. Need an even number of tasks: numtasks=%d\n", numtasks);
  } else {
    if (taskid == MASTER) 
      printf("MASTER: Number of MPI tasks is: %d\n",numtasks);

    MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &len);
    printf ("Hello from task %d on %s!\n", taskid, hostname);

    /* determine partner and then send/receive with partner */
    if (taskid < numtasks/2) {
      partner = numtasks/2 + taskid;
      MPI_Send(&taskid, 1, MPI_INT, partner, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Recv(&message, 1, MPI_INT, partner, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    } else if (taskid >= numtasks/2) {
      partner = taskid - numtasks/2;
      MPI_Recv(&message, 1, MPI_INT, partner, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Send(&taskid, 1, MPI_INT, partner, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    /* print partner info and exit*/
    printf("Task %d is partner with %d\n",taskid,message);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Something I am wondering about:

- Half the processes send before receiving, why does that happen?
- In case that all send before receiving, what would happen?

Comment: This is example of ping-pong messages - half would block and wait to receive anything, the other half will start sending. After they get their message, their roles are interchanged

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, in case that all send before receiving, it will just take longer to perform the exchange of messages?

Comment: Well, not sure why do you think it is longer. Say you have 10 processes. Number 0 will send  to number 5, 1 to 6, 2 to 7, 3 to 8 and 4 to 9. Those are blocking sends, 0,1,2,3,4 will each wait till message is really send to 5,6,7,8,9. Receiver will be waiting in blocking Recv() call, and as soon as they got message they are past block and go to their own Send() - 5 will be sending back to 0, 6 to 1, 7 to 2, 8 to 3, 9 to 4. Ping-pong. See example with 2 nodes here:http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all MPI tasks `MPI_Send()` and then `MPI_Recv()`, then it is incorrect with respect to the MPI standard.

The reason is `MPI_Send()` might block until a matching received is posted, and in your case, that would mean a deadlock.

In order to avoid the deadlock, and hence write a correct program, there are several options :

- order send and receive (e.g. half send then receive, and the other half receive and then send)
- use non blocking receive (e.g. all MPI tasks `MPI_Irecv()`, then `MPI_Send()` and finally `MPI_Wait()`
- use `MPI_Sendrecv()`, this is the best fit since your program exchanges data between two tasks.